# How to declare and refer to a js or css file contained in a Area in vNext?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, area

In vNext, there is a folder "wwwroot" which contain all js and css files, however if I create an Area and I want to create a css that apply only for that area I cant create the file inside the area and refer it later, because the area is not inside the wwwroot, so how this could be faced?